# How to determine if a graph is 3-colorable, given a way to determine for any graph if removing an edge from that graph gives a 3 colorable graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, coloring

The question is rather explicit, but I will restate it here:

Given the ability to determine whether there is an edge that can be removed from a given graph to give a 3-colorable graph, how can I find whether any given graph is 3-colorable?
(obviously we don't want a non-polynomial time algorithm)

Trying to add edges between all non-adjacent vertices of a the given graph G and repeatedly using the given ability won't work since the edge 'e' validating that G - e is 3-colorable might not have been added by our edge adding process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is about two decision problems.  Let me start with stating these two problems explicitly.  One is the usual 3-colorability:

**3-colorability**
*Instance*: A graph *G*=(*V*,*E*).
*Question*: Is *G* 3-colorable?

and the other is the following problem.  Because there is no standard name for the second problem, I just call it Problem X for the purpose of this answer.

**Problem X**
*Instance*: A graph *G*=(*V*,*E*).
*Question*: Is there an edge *e*∈*E* such that *G*−*e* is 3-colorable?

Suppose that we have the ability to solve Problem X and that we want to know whether a given graph *G*=(*V*,*E*) is 3-colorable or not.  Let *G*′=*G*+K<sub>4</sub> be the vertex-disjoint union of *G* and the complete graph on four vertices, and query the answer to Problem X on *G*′.  It is not hard to prove that the answer to Problem X on *G*′ is yes if and only if *G* is 3-colorable; the proof is left as an exercise.

In complexity theory, what you are asking for is called a *reduction* from 3-colorability to Problem X.